# What do the service values "CHECKPOINT" and "WAIT_HINT" mean?

Tags: windows, services, windows-services

I'm trying to troubleshoot some issues with a service, including a service not starting up properly. So I typed the command `sc queryex <servicename>` (documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/dd228921(v=ws.11))). Most of the results are fairly or at least somewhat clear - `SERVICE_NAME`, `TYPE`, `STATE`, `PID`.

But then there are two values that I have not been able to find any documentation anywhere about: `CHECKPOINT` and `WAIT_HINT`. What do the individual codes mean? All I get are hex values (e.g. 0x7530 or 0x61a8), but I can't find any explanation on what these actually mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange that the documentation about these values is so hard to find.
I finally managed to find it in the article
[Crate windows_service](https://docs.rs/windows-service/latest/windows_service/):

> When application that implements a windows service is launched by the
> system, it’s automatically put in the *StartPending* state.
>
> The application needs to complete the initialization, obtain
> *ServiceStatusHandle* (see *service_control_handler::register*) and transition to *Running* state.
>
> If service has a lengthy initialization, it should immediately tell
> the system how much time it needs to complete it, by sending the
> *StartPending* state, time estimate using **ServiceStatus::wait_hint** and increment **ServiceStatus::checkpoint** each time the service
> completes a step in initialization.
>
> The system will attempt to kill a service that is not able to
> transition to Running state before the proposed
> **ServiceStatus::wait_hint** expired.
>
> The same concept applies when transitioning between other pending
> states and their corresponding target states.

Comment: That's it! And weird that it's only possible to find that information in a _Rust_ documentation, of all places...

Answer (score 1):

I found some description in MSDN under [Win32_Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-service) class

- CheckPoint

> Value that the service increments periodically to report its progress during a long start, stop, pause, or continue operation. For example, the service increments this value as it completes each step of its initialization when it is starting up. The user interface program that invokes the operation on the service uses this value to track the progress of the service during a lengthy operation. This value is not valid and should be zero when the service does not have a start, stop, pause, or continue operation pending.

- WaitHint

> Estimated time required, in milliseconds, for a pending start, stop, pause, or continue operation. After the specified time has elapsed, the service makes its next call to the SetServiceStatus method with either an incremented CheckPoint value or a change in CurrentState. If the amount of time specified by WaitHint passes, and CheckPoint has not been incremented, or CurrentState has not changed, the service control manager or service control program assumes that an error has occurred.

Comment: That's it, this time in official documentation, thanks! Unfortunately I've already awarded an answer, but you have my upvote. Interesting that Google didn't find this page.